# Error in data.frame — replacement has [x] rows, data has [y] only when knitting to HTML

Tags: html, r, dataframe, r-markdown, knitr

I have an R Markdown file that I am trying to knit to HTML with `knitr`. In processing the file, it keeps getting hung up on a particular block of code. What I am trying to do is to filter the master data file, `REDCapTab`, using `dplyr`. I then make a new data frame (called `gestage` here) with one column and 10768 rows. I populate this column with the values of 16 columns from the master data file, essentially stacking these 16 columns into one. Each of the 16 columns has 673 rows and this matches the 10768 rows in the new data frame I made. I then convert this column in `gestage` to a factor with three levels and generate a bar plot. When I run all this code on the console, I don't get any error and I'm able to generate the bar plot without a problem. However, the problem comes when I try to knit this file to HTML. Below is my code from the R Markdown file where the error is occurring.

```
x <- REDCapTab %>% 
  filter(PTDbloods != 0 & (AllPTDhx == 1 | AllPTDhx == 4))
gestage <- data.frame(new_column = rep(NA, 10768))
gestage$new_column <- c(x$p1wk09, x$p2wk09, x$p3wk09, x$p4wk09, x$p5wk09, x$p6wk09, x$p7wk09, x$p8wk09, x$p9wk09, x$p10wk09, x$p11wk09, x$p12wk09, x$p13wk09, x$p14wk09, x$p15wk09, x$p16wk09)
gestage$new_column <- factor(gestage$new_column, levels = c("20-27 weeks", "28-31 weeks", "32-36 weeks"))

gest_age_sPTL <- barplot(table(gestage$new_column),
                    xlab = "Gestational Age",
                    ylab = "Frequency (#)",
                    ylim = c(0, 600),
                    col = "darkslategray2",
                    main = md("Gestational Age Distribution for Pure sPTL Cases (n = 673)"))
rm(list = c("gestage", "gest_age_sPTL", "x"))
```

Below is the error that I get:

```
processing file: NHS2CaseSelection.Rmd
                                                                                                                                       

Quitting from lines 584-597 [gest_age_pPROM] (NHS2CaseSelection.Rmd)
Error in `$<-.data.frame`:
! replacement has 0 rows, data has 5712
Backtrace:
 1. base::`$<-`(`*tmp*`, new_column, value = `<chr>`)
 2. base::`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, new_column, value = `<chr>`)
Execution halted
```

What I find strange is that no problem comes up in the console, just during the knitting process. I also have a very similar chunk of code immediately before this doing a similar process and no error comes up in knitting to HTML. I've attached that bit of code below in case it could help.

```
x <- filter(REDCapTab, PTDbloods != 0)
gestage <- data.frame(new_column = rep(NA, 40688))
gestage$new_column <- c(x$p1wk09, x$p2wk09, x$p3wk09, x$p4wk09, x$p5wk09, x$p6wk09, x$p7wk09, x$p8wk09, x$p9wk09, x$p10wk09, x$p11wk09, x$p12wk09, x$p13wk09, x$p14wk09, x$p15wk09, x$p16wk09)
gestage$new_column <- factor(gestage$new_column, levels = c("20-27 weeks", "28-31 weeks", "32-36 weeks"))

gest_age <- barplot(table(gestage$new_column),
        xlab = "Gestational Age",
        ylab = "Frequency (#)",
        ylim = c(0, 3000),
        col = "darkslategray2",
        main = "Gestational Age Distribution of Preterm Delivery Cases")
rm(list = c("gestage", "gest_age", "x"))
```

So far, I've tried creating my new data frame, `gestage`, in a variety of ways. I've tried making a vector with the column values using the `rep` function and then making the data frame with one column using the vector. I also tried applying the `as.data.frame` function on this vector. I also attempted to make the data frame using a sequence. No technique has worked and all generate the same error as above. It's worth mentioning that all these alternative techniques that I've tried have no problem running on the console, just when trying to knit to HTML.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: When you knit a document, all your code chunks are run, in order, in a fresh R session. When there is a difference between knitting a document and running code in the console, almost always the issue is that some code has been previously run in the console that changes the objects in the environment, and the issue arises because whatever that code is, it's not run when the document in knit. I would suggest restarting R and then running the code in all your chunks one at a time until you can reproduce the error.

Comment: At the end of the previous chunk (the one causing no errors), you have deleted `x` from the workspace `rm(list = c(... "x"))`. You then try to populate `gestage$new_column` with values pulled from `x`. Could this be your issue?

Comment: I would also suggest simplifying your code--there's no reason to create a new column of `NA` values of a certain length and then fill it in, rather go directly to `gestage <- data.frame(new_column = c(x$p1wk09, x$p2wk09, ...))`. This is cleaner, but based on your error I think you will find that `gestage` has 0 rows, because your error makes it sound like `x` has 0 rows, which suggests the problem is with the line `x <- filter(REDCapTab, PTDbloods != 0)`.

Comment: If I had to take a guess, I would bet that you don't have `library(dplyr)` in your knitr document, so when you run `x <- filter(REDCapTab, PTDbloods != 0)` you are using the built-in `stats::filter` instead of `dplyr::filter`, and that creates an `x` with 0 rows. But there are plenty of other possibilities too.

Comment: (Or, if you are extracting all the columns of the pattern `p*wk*` where the `*` values are numbers, something like `cols = grep("p\\d*wk\\d*", names(x)); gestage = data.frame(new_column = unlist(x[cols]))` might be nice. Not to fix the bug, but to simplify the code.)

Comment: @GregorThomas Thank you so much for the suggestions! I did have ```library(dplyr)``` in my document. When I simplified my code like you suggested, it resolved it. I appreciate your advice :)